# Internal Server Error / XHR error: [object Object] in jQuery $.ajax method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using a jQuery `$.ajax` method to fetch some data from a PHP script (`card-data.php`), and output it to a another PHP page.

When the jQuery runs, I receive an `Internal Server Error`, and when I `console.log` the `xhr` response I get this: `[object Object]`

*Edit* I can now view the entire xhr object thanks to @CBroe's comment

I've simplified and removed some "extra" code when posting here to simplify it a bit, but when I recreated my website with the code below I still got the same errors.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const cardsHidden = $('#cards-hidden');
    $.ajax({
        url: '../../php/includes/card/card-data.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){ 
            cardsHidden.html(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("AJAX error:", status, "Error:", error, "XHR:", xhr);
        }
    });
});
```

The PHP script (card-data.php):

```
<?php 
$sql       = 'SELECT username, name, age, FROM database ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3';
$result    = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $username   = [];
    $fullName   = [];
    $age        = [];
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $username[]   = $row['username'];
        $fullName[]   = $row['name'];
        $age[]        = $row['age'];
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>No posts to show...</p>';
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

The PHP page (output page):

```
<?php include 'card-data.php'; ?>

<div id="cards-hidden" class="card-wrapper --center-align">
    <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        echo '
        <div class="card'.$i.' card">
            <div class="card__title">
               <h5>'.$fullName[$i].', <span class="card__title--age">'.$age[$i].'</span></h5>
               <p class="card__title--username">('.$username[$i].')</p>
            </div>
        </div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: your `card-data.php` script is not echoing anything in case there is a result, so the response would be emtpy. Have you tried debugging your php script? Any error in there?

Comment: You are getting `[object Object]`, because you force the object into a string context, by concatenating it with other string values. Stop doing that, then you will be able to actually inspect the object and see what it contains. `console.log("AJAX error:", status, "Error:", error, "XHR:", xhr)`

Comment: @empiric Does card-data need to echo anything? I include it in the card.php file, and the uses its variables. I've recently also had the card-data.php written inside the card.php file, and I still had the same error. Nothing seems to be wrong with the php but I don't know...

Comment: @CBroe Thx, I can now view the entire object